# How do I map return in insert to go to normal mode and then do the o action

Tags: vim

I am currently using vim and I'd like to map the Return key (I'm on a mac. I believe that this is generally represented by `<ENTER>` in maps) to leave insert mode, and then perform the `o` action. I was trying to put something like this

```
imap <ENTER> <ESC>o
```

However this is not performing the desired action. Any help would be fantastic.

**Edit**: The desired action is that if I am typing in insert mode, each new line is a new action. So if I press undo in normal mode it just undoes the last line instead of all the lines typed while in insert mode.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works fine for me. Could you explain what exactly is going wrong? Also, I'm only posting this as a comment because it's only a guess but try `:inoremap <cr> <esc>o` instead, see if that works better.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem that doesn't work for me either. If I'm in insert mode and type `Code .... <CR> More Code...` I want `u` to undo just `More Code...` not everything typed. With both maps when I press `u` it undoes everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I do not know why escaping and using `o` to open a newline does not add to the change-list. However, lucky for us, there is a command for explicitly adding the current state of the text to the change list. That command is (in insert mode) `<C-g>u`. From `:h i_ctrl-g_u`

```
CTRL-G u    break undo sequence, start new change        *i_CTRL-G_u*
```

Conveniently, this command doesn't even leave insert mode! Putting it all together, the mapping you're looking for is:

```
:inoremap <cr> <C-g>u<cr>
```

Or, you could also do

```
:inoremap <cr> <cr><C-g>u
```

which will leave you with a blank line after undoing.

Comment: Thank you! While this wasn't the command I was looking for this serves to function exactly like what I wanted nonetheless. If I were writing it in `.vimrc` do I then write `inoremap <cr> <C-g>u<cr>`?

Comment: @EliSadoff Glad I could help! Yes, that is how you would write it in your `.vimrc`. Also, just FYI if you have more vim-related questions, we have a [dedicated vim-site](http://vi.stackexchange.com) you could post them on.

Comment: thanks! I had no idea. I was debating between here and SuperUser and went with here because text editors are sometimes in questions here.